# В чем заключается семантика константного метода?

Tags: c++, методы, const

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Aggregation
{
    public:
    Object* get() const
    {
        return object;
    }

    private:
    Object* object;
};
```

Метод `get()` предоставляет доступ к объекту, на который (возможно) указывает `object`.

Я не могу понять, в каком случае нужно считать метод `get()` константным, а в каком нет? Есть ли для этого устоявшийся набор правил?

Например, в данном случае метод не меняет состояние указателя `object`, и компилятор считает, что метод не изменяет состояние объекта класса `Aggregation`.

Но я могу объявить метод неконстантным, сказав: **изменение подобъекта через указатель `object` меняет состояние объекта класса `Aggregation`.**

И, формально, я буду прав?

Comment: Судя по статье http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/09/const-2.html метод `get` должен возвращать `Object* const`, и изменять объект через этот указатель не получится.

Comment: *"Есть ли для этого устоявшийся набор правил?"* Ну, например `.get()` умных указателей всегда возвращает неконстантный указатель. А `.data()` контейнеров возвращает константный указатель только если сам вектор константный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод **нужно** объявлять константным если он может быть вызван для константных объектов. Этот метод не имеет право менять значения собственных переменных. Все другие функции без **const** декларации допускаться не будут.

На объект куда направлен указатель константность не распространяется. ( *Object* **const** object;* ) Вы имеете право сами назначать уровень доступа в своей программе.

---

Для удобства баго устойчивости **const** придумали. На самом деле вам нужно написать куча вариантов метода. Это позволит обезопасить переменную **object** от случайных изменений. Вот пример возврата простого указателя и константного. Всё зависит от константности самого объекта.

```
class Composition
{
    public:
    Object* get()
    {
        return object;
    }
    Object const * get() const
    {
        return object;
    }
    Object const * const_get()const
    {
        return object;
    }
    Object * free_get() const
    {
        return object ;
    }
    private:
    Object* object;
};
```

Но вы можете всегда возвращать на константный объект в любом случае. Или всегда свободный. Всё зависит от вашей программы , семантики этого объекта.

Answer (score 3):

Неконстантные методы вызываются только для неконстантных объектов. Методы со спецификаторами const являются явным указанием того, что метод не изменяет состояние объекта, и этот метод можно вызвать для константных объектов. Значит, когда нужно получать некоторую информацию  об объекте, то мы делаем метод константным, чтобы была возможность получать эту информацию и о константных объектах

Answer (score 1):

Формально, в ООП не рассматривается понятие "указателя", но понятие "ссылка" выводится из такого взаимоотношения классов, когда Агрегатор заинтересован в конкретных экземплярах определенного класса.

Строчки зрения формального ООП, указатель на тип есть всего лишь тип. То, как он трактуется некоторым контекстом не имеет значения. Потому, если член класса типа some_type, а тип возвращаемого значения some_type*, то модификатор функции-члена const относится только к методу, к его коду, который не изменяет значение типа some_type*.

Данный const не относится к использованию метода и значению для предметной модели.

Неизменность состояния класса лучше всего на текущий момент выражается через наименование метода.